# Why does CDI injection fail to work in a some modules, but not in others?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld

In my Java EE project, there are several "Java EE" modules and a web module.
One of the Java EE modules provides a class to CDI that is to be used by the other modules:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class XFactory {

  @Produces @Actual
  public X create() {
     return new X();
  }
}
```

They are injected into

```
   @SessionScoped
   public class Target implements Serializable {
       X x;

      @Inject
      public void setX(@Actual X x){
        this.x = x;
      }
   }
```

However, this works only in one of the Java EE modules and in the web module. In all of the remaining Java EE modules, injection consistently fails, and I am clueless as to why: All I get is  *WELD-1408, unsatisfied dependency*.

All of the modules have `beans.xml` in the proper places, they all work as long as I don't switch to injection. Most of the target beans are already in use as injected beans in  a JSF.
What's special about the Java EE module that works is that the bean is injected into a servlet in the web module, not the JSF.

The project runs with Java EE 6, EJB 3.1 in GlassFish 3.1. Dependencies are managed by Maven 3. `X` itself is `Serializable`, to satisfy the passivating scopes.

Did you come across this before? What could I have done wrong?

*Update*: Added dependency management remark above.

*Update*: Corrected the position of `@Actual` in `Target`.

*Update*: Updated the description with more details after a day of experiments.

Comment: No answers as yet. I am going to re-write the module step by step and see at which point injection fails to work. Still appreciating your input, though.

Comment: There seems to be more amiss than I first thought. My statement that everything works just fine outside of that single project might have been wrong:
Injection fails even in the simplest of modules.
I am starting to wonder why it works in one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem in Glassfish 3.1, in one of its included libraries, or possibly in JDK 6.

I have just updated my system to Glassfish 3.1.1 and JDK 7, and problem does not occur any longer.

Comment: I will investigate some more while replacing the `X`s with production code before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my recent experience on Weblogic I discovered that namespaces containing underscores prevents EJB modules to get any beans injected.

I suggest you to give a try on Glassfish too.

Regards!

Comment: You realize this has been answered 9 years ago?

Comment: Do you realize that my answer may be useful to somebody else in the future?